# Indicating a lost signal when streaming live video with GStreamer and Qt

Tags: c++, qt

The goal of the code is to display a live camera feed sent by GStreamer over UDP, and to give an indication of when the signal is lost by displaying a static blue screen instead of the last frozen frame. Qt is used to display the image, and to provide a label, and a button for taking snapshots.

I would be interested in any suggestions for improvements, but especially for improving speed and efficiency.

[main.cpp]

```
// For testing: gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! video/x-raw,format=GRAY8 ! videoconvert ! x264enc pass=qual quantizer=20 tune=zerolatency ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=224.1.1.1 port=5000

// It seems that g_signal_connect needs to be called before QObject::connect.

#include <QApplication>

#include <QCommandLineParser>

#include <iostream>

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "acquisitiontype.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QCommandLineParser parser;

    QString label_font;
    const QString default_label_font = "Courier";

    qreal label_point_size;
    const QString default_label_point_size = "14";
    const qreal min_label_point_size = 6;
    const qreal max_label_point_size = 72;

    QStringList args;

    const unsigned short expected_args_count = 3;

    QString address;
    QString port;
    QString label_text;


    parser.addHelpOption();

    QCommandLineOption label_fontOption("f", "Label font", "font", default_label_font);
    parser.addOption(label_fontOption);

    QCommandLineOption label_point_sizeOption("s", "Label point size", "size", default_label_point_size);
    parser.addOption(label_point_sizeOption);

    parser.addPositionalArgument("address", "Address");
    parser.addPositionalArgument("port", "Port");
    parser.addPositionalArgument("label", "Label text");

    parser.process(app);

    label_font = parser.value(label_fontOption);

    label_point_size = parser.value(label_point_sizeOption).toDouble();
    label_point_size = label_point_size > min_label_point_size ? label_point_size : min_label_point_size;
    label_point_size = label_point_size < max_label_point_size ? label_point_size : max_label_point_size;

    args = parser.positionalArguments();

    if (args.count() < expected_args_count) {
        std::cout << parser.helpText().toLatin1().data() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "error: too few arguments" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    else if (args.count() > expected_args_count) {
        std::cout << parser.helpText().toLatin1().data() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "error: unrecognized arguments: " << QStringList(args.mid(expected_args_count, -1)).join(" ").toLatin1().data() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    address = args.at(0);
    port = args.at(1);
    label_text = args.at(2);


    AcquisitionType acquisition(address.toLatin1(), port.toInt());

    MainWindow window(label_text, label_font, label_point_size);

    QObject::connect(&acquisition, SIGNAL(setData(const QPixmap&)), &window, SLOT(setData(const QPixmap&)));

    window.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

[mainwindow.cpp]

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QString label_text, QString label_font, qreal label_point_size) {
    QFont font;


    centralWidget = new QWidget;
    layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    labelWidget = new QLabel;
    imageWidget = new ImageType;
    buttonWidget = new QPushButton;
    dialogWidget = new QFileDialog;


    labelWidget->setText(label_text);
    font.setFamily(label_font);
    font.setPointSizeF(label_point_size);
    labelWidget->setFont(font);
    labelWidget->setAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter);
    QSizePolicy labelWidget_size_policy(QSizePolicy::Preferred, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
    labelWidget->setSizePolicy(labelWidget_size_policy);

    layout->addWidget(labelWidget);


    layout->addWidget(imageWidget);


    QSizePolicy buttonWidget_size_policy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
    buttonWidget->setSizePolicy(buttonWidget_size_policy);
    buttonWidget->setIcon(QIcon::fromTheme("camera-photo"));
    buttonWidget->setIconSize(QSize(24, 24));
    buttonWidget->setEnabled(false);

    layout->addWidget(buttonWidget);


    dialogWidget->setFileMode(QFileDialog::AnyFile);
    dialogWidget->setAcceptMode(QFileDialog::AcceptSave);
    dialogWidget->setNameFilter("Images (*.png)");
    dialogWidget->setDefaultSuffix(".png");


    QObject::connect(buttonWidget, SIGNAL(clicked()), imageWidget, SLOT(setSnapshot()));
    QObject::connect(buttonWidget, SIGNAL(clicked()), dialogWidget, SLOT(show()));
    QObject::connect(dialogWidget, SIGNAL(fileSelected(QString)), imageWidget, SLOT(saveSnapshot(QString)));


    centralWidget->setLayout(layout);

    setCentralWidget(centralWidget);

    setWindowTitle("GigE Camera - " + label_text);

    resize(500, 500);
}

void MainWindow::setData(const QPixmap& pixmap) {
    if (!pixmap.isNull()) {
        buttonWidget->setEnabled(true);
    }
    else {
        buttonWidget->setEnabled(false);
    }

    imageWidget->setData(pixmap);
}
```

[mainwindow.h]

```
#include "imagetype.h"

#include <QMainWindow>

#include <QVBoxLayout>

#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QFileDialog>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QString label_text, QString label_font, qreal label_point_size);

public slots:
    void setData(const QPixmap& pixmap);

private:
    QVBoxLayout* layout;
    QLabel* labelWidget;
    ImageType* imageWidget;
    QPushButton* buttonWidget;
    QFileDialog* dialogWidget;
    QWidget* centralWidget;
};
```

[acquisitiontype.cpp]

```
#include "acquisitiontype.h"

// From the documentation for the QImage constructor: "The buffer must remain valid throughout the life of the QImage and all copies that have not been modified or otherwise detached from the original buffer." This is why a QPixmap copy of the QImage is sent instead of the QImage. If the QImage is sent then the buffer is not valid at the end of this callback and before the QImage is used in the slot function. The QPixmap copy is not reliant on the buffer remaining valid.
GstFlowReturn AcquisitionType::new_sample_callback(GstAppSink* appsink, gstreamer_data* user_data) {
    GstSample* sample;
    GstCaps* caps;
    GstStructure* s;
    GstBuffer* buffer;
    GstMapInfo map;
    QImage image;
    QPixmap pixmap;
    int width;
    int height;


    sample = gst_app_sink_pull_sample(appsink);
    if (sample) {
        caps = gst_sample_get_caps(sample);
        if (caps) {
            s = gst_caps_get_structure(caps, 0);

            if (gst_structure_get_int(s, "width", &width) && gst_structure_get_int(s, "height", &height)) {
                buffer = gst_sample_get_buffer(sample);

                if (buffer) {
                    if (gst_buffer_map(buffer, &map, GST_MAP_READ)) {
                        //printf("have sample\n");

                        image = QImage(map.data, width, height, QImage::Format_RGBX8888);
                        pixmap.convertFromImage(image);

                        gst_buffer_unmap(buffer, &map);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        gst_sample_unref(sample);
    }

    emit (user_data->instance)->setData(pixmap);

    return GST_FLOW_OK;
}

GstPadProbeReturn AcquisitionType::udp_source_buffer_pad_probe_callback(GstPad* pad, GstPadProbeInfo* info, gstreamer_data* user_data) {
    (void) pad;
    (void) info;
    GstBus* bus;


    //printf("have data\n");

    bus = gst_element_get_bus(user_data->pipeline);
    user_data->signal_handler_id = g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(bus), "message::element", (GCallback) udp_source_timeout_callback, user_data);
    gst_object_unref(bus);

    return GST_PAD_PROBE_REMOVE;
}

void AcquisitionType::udp_source_timeout_callback(GstBus* bus, GstMessage* message, gstreamer_data* user_data) {
    const GstStructure* st = gst_message_get_structure(message);
    GstPad* pad;
    QPixmap pixmap;


    if (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE(message) == GST_MESSAGE_ELEMENT) {
        if (gst_structure_has_name(st, "GstUDPSrcTimeout")) {
            //printf("no data\n");

            // Sends a null pixmap.
            emit (user_data->instance)->setData(pixmap);

            g_signal_handler_disconnect(G_OBJECT(bus), user_data->signal_handler_id);

            pad = gst_element_get_static_pad(user_data->udp_source, "src");
            gst_pad_add_probe(pad, GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_BUFFER, (GstPadProbeCallback) udp_source_buffer_pad_probe_callback, user_data, NULL);
            gst_object_unref(pad);
        }
    }
}

void AcquisitionType::bus_error_callback(GstBus* bus, GstMessage* message, gstreamer_data* user_data) {
    (void) bus;
    (void) user_data;
    GError* err;
    gchar* debug_info;


    gst_message_parse_error(message, &err, &debug_info);
    g_printerr("Error received from element %s: %s\n", GST_OBJECT_NAME(message->src), err->message);
    g_printerr("Debugging information: %s\n", debug_info ? debug_info : "none");
    g_clear_error(&err);
    g_free(debug_info);

    exit(-1);
}

AcquisitionType::AcquisitionType(char const* address, gint port) {
    GstStateChangeReturn ret;
    GstBus* bus;


    gst_init(NULL, NULL);


    data.instance = this;

    data.udp_source = gst_element_factory_make("udpsrc", "udp_source");
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(data.udp_source),
        "address", address,
        "port", port,
        "caps", gst_caps_new_empty_simple("application/x-rtp"),
        "timeout", G_GUINT64_CONSTANT(1000000000),
        NULL);

    data.rtp_decoder = gst_element_factory_make("rtph264depay", "rtp_decoder");

    data.video_decoder = gst_element_factory_make("avdec_h264", "video_decoder");

    data.video_converter = gst_element_factory_make("videoconvert", "video_converter");

    data.app_sink = gst_element_factory_make("appsink", "app_sink");
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(data.app_sink),
        "emit-signals", true,
    "max-buffers", G_GUINT64_CONSTANT(1),
        "drop", true,
        "caps", gst_caps_new_simple("video/x-raw", "format", G_TYPE_STRING, "RGBx", NULL),
        NULL);

    g_signal_connect(data.app_sink, "new-sample", (GCallback) new_sample_callback, &data);

    data.pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("pipeline");


    if (
        !data.pipeline ||
        !data.udp_source ||
        !data.rtp_decoder ||
        !data.video_decoder ||
        !data.video_converter ||
        !data.app_sink
        )
        {
            g_printerr("Not all elements could be created.\n");
            exit(-1);
        }


    gst_bin_add_many(
        GST_BIN(data.pipeline),
        data.udp_source,
        data.rtp_decoder,
        data.video_decoder,
        data.video_converter,
        data.app_sink,
        NULL);


    if (gst_element_link_many(
        data.udp_source,
        data.rtp_decoder,
        data.video_decoder,
        data.video_converter,
        data.app_sink,
        NULL) != TRUE)
        {
            g_printerr("Elements could not be linked.\n");
            gst_object_unref(data.pipeline);
            exit(-1);
        }


    bus = gst_element_get_bus(data.pipeline);
    gst_bus_add_signal_watch(bus);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(bus), "message::error", (GCallback) bus_error_callback, &data);
    data.signal_handler_id = g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(bus), "message::element", (GCallback) udp_source_timeout_callback, &data);
    gst_object_unref(bus);


    ret = gst_element_set_state(data.pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
    if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
        g_printerr("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.\n");
        gst_object_unref(data.pipeline);
        exit(-1);
    }
}

AcquisitionType::~AcquisitionType() {
    GstBus* bus;


    gst_element_set_state(data.pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);

    bus = gst_element_get_bus(data.pipeline);
    gst_bus_remove_signal_watch(bus);
    gst_object_unref(bus);

    gst_object_unref(data.pipeline);
}
```

[acquisitiontype.h]

```
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <gst/app/gstappsink.h>

#include <QObject>

#include <QPixmap>

class AcquisitionType;

struct gstreamer_data {
    GstElement* pipeline;
    GstElement* udp_source;
    GstElement* rtp_decoder;
    GstElement* video_decoder;
    GstElement* video_converter;
    GstElement* app_sink;
    gulong signal_handler_id;
    AcquisitionType* instance;
};


class AcquisitionType : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    AcquisitionType(char const* address, gint port);
    ~AcquisitionType();

signals:
    void setData(const QPixmap&);

private:
    static GstFlowReturn new_sample_callback(GstAppSink* appsink, gstreamer_data* user_data);
    static GstPadProbeReturn udp_source_buffer_pad_probe_callback(GstPad* pad, GstPadProbeInfo* info, gstreamer_data* user_data);
    static void udp_source_timeout_callback(GstBus* bus, GstMessage* message, gstreamer_data* user_data);
    static void bus_error_callback(GstBus* bus, GstMessage* message, gstreamer_data* user_data);

    gstreamer_data data;
};
```

[imagetype.cpp]

```
#include "imagetype.h"

#include <QPainter>

void ImageType::setData(const QPixmap& pixmap) {
    this->pixmap = pixmap;

    this->repaint();
}

void ImageType::setSnapshot() {
    this->snapshot = this->pixmap;
}

void ImageType::saveSnapshot(QString filename) {
    this->snapshot.save(filename, "PNG");
}

void ImageType::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event) {
    (void) event;
    QPainter painter(this);
    QPixmap scaled;


    if (!pixmap.isNull()) {
        scaled = pixmap.scaled(this->size(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation);
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, scaled);
    }
    else {
        painter.fillRect(this->rect(), QColor("blue"));
    }
}
```

[imagetype.h]

```
#include <QWidget>

class ImageType : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    ImageType(QWidget* parent = nullptr) : QWidget(parent) {};
    void setData(const QPixmap& pixmap);
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event);

public slots:
    void setSnapshot();
    void saveSnapshot(QString filename);

private:
    QPixmap pixmap;
    QPixmap snapshot;
};
```

[Qt project file]

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2018-10-25T11:34:49
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = gst_gige_camera
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp \
        acquisitiontype.cpp \
        imagetype.cpp

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h \
        acquisitiontype.h \
        imagetype.h

INCLUDEPATH += $$system(pkg-config --cflags gstreamer-1.0)

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += $$system(pkg-config --cflags gstreamer-1.0)

LIBS += $$system(pkg-config --libs gstreamer-1.0 gstreamer-app-1.0)

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```